# Huge lists in multiprocessing make it stuck, even when using 'processes=1"

Tags: python, list, dictionary, multiprocessing

I need to process huge lists: the main loop has 500 000 elements and it uses look up dict with 200 000 elements.

The function is working but it's quite slow, so I've tried to use multiprocessing.

But my multiprocessing function is stuck at the first line of its function (It never prints `inside multiprocessing_func`). There is no errors. When multiprocessing a shorter list and dicts, it's working normally.

It looks like a problem of memory use (all my other open programs like the browser for ex. run slowly when this got stuck), but I don't know how to improve this.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import repeat

def multiprocessing_func(huge_list_keys1, huge_list_keys2, 
                        huge_lookup_dict):
    print('inside multiprocessing_func') # <-- It's never displayed
    
    # look for items inside dicts
    found1 = huge_lookup_dict[huge_list_keys1)
    found2 = huge_lookup_dict[huge_list_keys2)
    ...

# we are looping on "huge_list_keys1" and "huge_list_keys2" (they have the same length) and we
# use some dict "huge_lookup_dict" which is used in the lookup processing function.
zipped_args = zip(
  huge_list_keys1,
  huge_list_keys2, 
  repeat(huge_lookup_dict)                         
)
with manager.Pool(processes=1) as pool: # <-- I've tried with only ONE process or more: same problem of getting stuck.
  print('launching multi-process:')# <-- this is printed normally
  pool.starmap(multiprocessing_func, zipped_args)
```

None of the lists and dicts are shared so I didn't have to create shared objects with `manager.list()` or `manager.dict().`

Comment: You forgot to precede your code with `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: It's a snippet inside a bigger program. It's not meant to be run independently.

Comment: but how would I know? I can only see what you post.

Comment: The program wouldn't even run if the error came from that!

Comment: `with manager.Pool`? Do you mean `with multiprocessing.Pool`?

Comment: There are solutions to these types of problems, but only when you actually post what you are actually doing. For example, where do these key lists come from? What does `huge_lookup_dict` actualy do? What is ultimately done by `multiprocessing_func` when the key is found, i.e. is data written out or is data returned and then written out? No reasonable answer can be given until this information is provided. This may not even be a candidate for multiprocessing and certainly running multiprocessing with a pool size of 1 is guaranteed to run more slowly than not using multiprocessing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `if __name__ == "__main__":`

```py
...
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # we are looping on "huge_list_keys1" and "huge_list_keys2" (they have the same length) and we
    # use some dict "huge_lookup_dict" which is used in the lookup processing function.
    zipped_args = zip(
      huge_list_keys1,
      huge_list_keys2, 
      repeat(huge_lookup_dict)                         
    )
    with manager.Pool(processes=1) as pool: # <-- I've tried with only ONE process or more: same problem of getting stuck.
      print('launching multi-process:')# <-- this is printed normally
      pool.starmap(multiprocessing_func, zipped_args)
```

Comment: It's a snippet inside a bigger program. It's not meant to be run independently.